# Not able to understand flow after return statement execution

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm having trouble with this code:

```js
function foo(i) {

  if (i < 0) {

    return;
  }
  console.log('begin:' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end:' + i);
}
foo(2);
```

```
begin:2
begin:1
begin:0
end:0
end:1
end:2
>>undefined
```

Not sure why

```
end:0  
end:1
end:2
```

are getting printed on console.

After return statement execution value of I getting again positive.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Please note the corrections to the question in my edit. When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving help. *And* a preview area between the text area and the Post button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to get you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Not sure what you are unclear over to be fair. The directive `return` does exactly what it says and returns to the point in the code where the function was called. So first loop (i=2) `foo()` is called but never returns because it calls `foo()` again with i=1 and then again with i=0. After that the last foo(i=0) will return to the foo(i=1) and it will in turn return to foo(i=2) and that will finally return to the main context where it was first called (the line under `foo(2)`.

Comment: Try to follow the program flow by hand (or in your head) and see how recursion impacts it.

Answer (score 7):

Lets just walk through it.

```
foo(2);
 // logs out begin: 2;
 // calls foo(1);
    // logs out begin: 1;
    // calls foo(0);
       // logs out begin: 0;
       // calls foo(-1);
          // pop up
       // logs out end: 0;
       // pop up
    // logs out end: 1;
    // pop up
 // logs out end: 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing this because `foo` is calling itself. So `foo`

- Outputs the "begin:" line
- Calls itself
- Outputs the "end:" line

When it calls itself, of course, it does the same thing. So:

```
foo(2) outputs "begin:2"
foo(2) calls foo(1):
    foo(1) outputs "begin:1"
    foo(1) calls foo(0)
        foo(0) outputs "begin:0"
        foo(0) calls foo(-1)
            foo(-1) returns before printing anything
        foo(0) outputs "end:0"
        foo(0) returns
    foo(1) outputs "end:1"
    foo(1) returns
foo(2) outputs "end:2"
foo(2) returns
```

Comment: @Neal: Well, they're very, very similar. :-) When I posted mine and then saw yours, I deleted mine. Then I thought "Well, dunno, maybe the slightly different terminology will help..."

Comment: I saw that TJ, but yours **does** add some more detail

Answer (score 0):

Your function call when returned will carry on from where it left off.  In each case in your code it left off just before printing the `end` statements.  So each function call as they exit will continue on to print the end statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because that is how recursive function calls work.

You have this code snippet:

```
console.log('begin:' + i);
foo(i - 1);
console.log('end:' + i);`
```

In this case, the last line won't be ignored just because the function does another call before. `console.log('end:' + i);` will be added to the call stack each time, so when the recursive function calls `foo(i - 1);` are done, then the function will continue execution as it was supposed to do until it reaches the end.